# Is the following argument legal?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Say we have $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}$ that absolutely converges and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_{n}$ converges. Say we also have $f$ that is continuous at $x=0$. I have to prove $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}f(b_{n})$ absolutely converges. Now my idea was - $f$ is continuous at $0$, so we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(b_{n})=f(0)$.
Let's denote $S_{p}=\sum_{n=1}^{p}a_{n}f(b_{n})$.

Now, we can say $\lim_{p\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{p}a_{n}f(b_{n})=f(0)\lim_{p\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{p}a_{n}$.
We know $\lim_{p\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{p}a_{n}$ exists because $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ converges, so the original limit exists. Is this argument valid?
Or what other way is there to approach such problem?

Comment: Your argument has a little problem, which you must solve in the step $\lim_{p\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{p}a_{n}f(b_{n})=f(0)\lim_{p\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{p}a_{n}$. What allows you "to sum up" only for $\;f(b_n)\;$ but not for $\;a_N\;$ ?

Comment: That's exactly my question. I never encountered this sort of argument before so I was not sure sure if it's legal at-all. It is problematic as I see it but I couldn't figure why.

Comment: But I'm guessing you've already studied limits, and you must know you cannot take a part of the limit and leave the other one fixed: $$e=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\neq\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)\right)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}1^n=1$$ That is: you cannot usually take one part of the expression in the limit, resolve and let other part unresolved.

Answer (score 4):

You must show that $\sum_n |a_n f(b_n)| < \infty$ (this is absolute convergence) and your attempt does not say anything about this. Here is how I would approach this problem:

Since $\sum_n b_n$ converges, we have $b_n \to 0$. Consequently since $f$ is continuous in $0$, $f(b_n) \to f(0)$. In particular, $(f(b_n))_n$ is a bounded sequence so there is $M \geq 0$ such that $|f(b_n)| \leq M$ for all $n \geq 0$. Then
$$\sum_n |a_n f(b_n)| \leq \sum_n |a_n| M = M \sum_n |a_n|< \infty$$
and we can conclude.